# Serialization using DataContract, how to eliminate unneeded metadata ?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

In my game I have something called : `BaseTile` , inherited by many tiles, one of them is `WallTile`, i want to serialize it, I have added the `[DataContract]` attribute above `BaseTile` and `WallTile`, Added the `KnownType` attribute above `BaseTile` and added few `DataMember` attribute above several members :

```
    [DataMember]
    public TileType MyType; //TileType is just an enum
    [DataMember]
    protected Color mOverlay = Color.White;
    [DataMember]
    private Point mSize;
```

When i serialize it using `DataContractSerializer`, i get the following result : 
[image]

How do i avoid all the "xlmns:a=".................." ? 
It makes my file 3 times bigger, is it necessary? 
Why does he add this ?

Comment: Of course it is necessary, this is the way how xml and serializers works.

Comment: can you elaborate on this a little bit .. it seems like some useless information